# SUM child column of tableadapter

Tags: c#, ado.net, tableadapter

I have a tableadapter (`SettlementCurrentTableAdapter`) with a relation. parent table is (`SettlementCurrent`) child table is (`Trips`).

I need to SUM each row (`tripLoadedMiles`) in (`Trips`) and display the total in a label (`labelWelcomeSetTotalMiles`).

I would like to do this in code and not sql as i use this tableadapter to display other labels.

Can someone help me figure this out. i am new to C# and i use Visual C#.

```
        this.settlementCurrentTableAdapter.Fill(this.myLeaseDataSet.SettlementCurrent);
        MyLeaseDataSet.SettlementCurrentRow settlementCurrent;
        settlementCurrent = myLeaseDataSet.SettlementCurrent.Last();

        var settlementCurrentID = settlementCurrent.setID;

        this.tripsTableAdapter.FillByTripSetID(this.myLeaseDataSet.Trips, settlementCurrentID);
        MyLeaseDataSet.TripsDataTable settlementTrips;
        settlementTrips = myLeaseDataSet.Trips;
        foreach (DataRow row in myLeaseDataSet.Trips.Rows) 
        {

            NOT SURE ON THE CODE HERE

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first step is to extract the data you want out of your data adapter.  Since I don't have a table model in your question, it is best to look at the [table adapter overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN, and click on the related links and articles to figure out the basic usage of this object.  If you were to post your table structure, I could theoretically give you some code for it, but I'm reluctant to do that - you will have to work with this object a lot of it's how you're talking to your database, so it's imperative you learn how it functions.

Your goal in this learning is to figure out how to get all the miles figures out of your table adapter.  You usually do this by going over one row at a time, and picking out the values you want to add them to a more C# idiomatic data structure, such as a a `List`/`IEnumerable`, or an `Array`.

After you have the data you need in one of these structures, you can get the sum of everything by using LINQ.  Depending on how much you pulled out, it can be as simple as one call (if this is something like an `Array` of `ints`):

```
var totalMiles = tripLoadedMiles.Sum();
```

Or as elaborate as you might need (if this is a `List` of a custom object that has both `SettlementCurrentId` and `Miles`, both stored as `int`s):

```
var totalMiles = tripLoadedMiles.Select(x => x.SettlementCurrentId == someRandomRequiredSettlement).Sum(y => y.Miles);
```

In the way you're using things, this is how you're looking at totaling it in this situation.

```
    var total = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row in myLeaseDataSet.Trips.Rows) 
    {

        total += int.Parse(row["tripTotalMiles"].ToString());
    }
    // Use the total
```

Comment: Ok added code. however i am totally confused and im pretty sure im going about it all wrong. i have been reading through the msdn but it seems to just cunfuse me more

Comment: @user1804465 You are not even getting anything out of your data adapter.  The code I put in there is absolutely not going to work if you don't have anything for it to function on.  I am updating my answer with a few more resources for you to look at - again though, since I don't know what your underlying table structure looks like, *you will have to figure this out for yourself.*

Comment: Maybe im on the right path. filled the (SettlementCurrent) table adapter. then filled the (trips) table adapter by (setID). i cannot figure out what i use in the (myLeaseDataSet.Trips.SOMETHING();)

Comment: @user1804465 Is `Trips` a `DataTable`?  If so, try `foreach (DataRow row in myLeaseDataSet.Trips)`.  That should get you each individual row with the miles and whatever else in them, so you can do whatever you want.

Comment: it is a datatable. i updated my code in the original question.

Comment: @user1804465 Yeah, try that `foreach` loop I mentioned in my comment.  It'll get you individual `DataRow` objects, which will then let you do something like `DataRow["miles"]` and get the miles you want.  You can probably just get a sum of all that inside the `foreach`.  Let me know if that works and I'll update my answer.  If you've never used `foreach` before, [here's an explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: wouldn't i be looking for datacolumn since i want to sum each row in a column. not sure what to do with DataRow["tripLoadedMiles"]. when i use it in a variable it gives error type used as variable.

Comment: @user1804465 You're basically doing the same thing here.  You're pulling out a specific column that you're interested in, using each row.  If you were to pull out the column itself you'd still have to go over each column to get the values you need.  You can try pulling out the column if you like that more, though.  Also, looks like I goofed, it should be `foreach (DataRow row in myLeaseDataSet.Trips.Rows)`.  That might be why you're getting an error.  Also be sure you are doing `row["tripLoadedMiles"]`. If not, use the `immediate window` to play with the Row a bit to see what the structure is.

Comment: @user1804465 Incidentally, please avoid moving this to chat as I can't access it right now.  We will simply clean up our comments after we've resolved your problem.

Comment: could you look at at my code up top and possibly guide my as to how this process works. i have been racking my brain on this piece of code and cannot quite figure it out. i have found multiple different ways to accomplish this task but every way i try i seem to be missing something.

Comment: @user1804465 reread my comment.  `row["tripLoadedMiles"]` is what you're looking for.  `tripLoadedMiles` might change to be whatever the column is named, but yeah.

Comment: Yeah im still lost on where to put the `row["tripLoadedMiles"]`. before the `foreach` or inside. plus how to use the `row["tripLoadedMiles"]` with the `.Sum`. `row["tripLoadedMiles"].Sum` doesnt work

Comment: @user1804465 Inside the `foreach`.  Don't worry about `Sum` right now.  Just get the miles out of there and add it up manually.  You can figure out how to turn it into a one-liner later.

Comment: i appreciate your help. however apparently i am out of my league on this one. it has officially become easier for me to just track this on paper since i cannot for the life of me figure out what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: @user1804465 I went ahead and spelled it out longhand for anyone who happens to come across this question so take a look at it, I guess.  This really was not hard at all, so I have difficulty understanding what was so complicated.

Comment: Thank you. i am very visual. i believe i understand how that is working. 
i added that and the project builds with no errors. however the calculation is 0. so i must not be pulling data into the foreach. i have declared datatables that contain one item but never multiple items. can you help with that topic.

Comment: @user1804465 You should probably check to make sure you're properly getting in there, first.  Do you know how to set breakpoints?  If not, google breakpoints in visual studio real fast.  After that, drop a breakpoint on `var total = 0` and step through the program using `F10`.  Make sure you are getting in to the loop.  If not, you are not getting a properly loaded `DataTable`.  If you are, use the `Immediate Window` to check what the value of `row["tripTotalMiles"].ToString()` is.  It should be a number greater than zero.  If it's not, your data rows are messed up.

Comment: it steps to tthe foreach statement but boes not step into the curly brackets. it just skips the curly brackets. does that mean i do not have a properly loaded data table?

Comment: @user1804465 Correct.  Your Datatable exists, but there are no rows in it.  You will have to check how you're filling it from the database.